# Рандомное аниме с сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, бот

Хочу чтобы рандомное аниме брало с сайта по параметрам, а не получается. Я так понял, это надо на исходный код страницы смотреть и с этим что-то решать.

```
def check(message): # Все фильтры идут сюда
    return message.author.id == ctx.author.id and message.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
try:
    film = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    genre = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    country = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    year = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    params = {
        'option1': film,
        'option2': genre,
        'option3': country,
        'option4': year
    }
    # resp = requests.get('https://anime777.ru/random', params)
    # conv = resp.json()
    print(params)
    await ctx.send("Вы ввели такие параметры: " + film.content + ' ' + genre.content + ' ' + country.content + ' ' + year.content + " Вот аниме, которое можете посмотреть" )
    resp = requests.get('https://anime777.ru/random', params)
    conv = resp.json()
    await ctx.send("Пжлст, ваше аниме ёпт..." + conv)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send('Время вышло...')
```

Comment: Рулетка аниме https://anime777.ru/api/rand?type=&genre=&country=&year= ответ в JSON

Comment: await ctx.send("Пжлст, ваше аниме ёпт..." + conv)  весь JSON уходит пользователю. Так задумано?

Comment: Да, так и задумано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests

type_ = ''
genre = ''
country = ''
year = ''

resp = requests.get(f'https://anime777.ru/api/rand?type={type_}'
                    f'&genre={genre}&country{country}=&year={year}').json()
print(resp['title'])
print(resp['other_title'])
```

принт рандом

```
Последняя фантазия: Легенда кристаллов
Final Fantasy: Legend of the Crystals
```

Comment: requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] : 0
Вот такую ошибку выдает

Comment: Мною привиденный код отрабатывает на все 100%. Ищите ошибку у себя

Comment: Не я понял. Он все выводит. Только я хотел, чтобы параметры сам пользователь вводил. Ну это ладно. Я неправильно вопрос видимо поставил. Спасибо!

Comment: В общем, я проработал и он вроде все верно выдаёт.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, нужно было просто ссылку распределить

```
from email import header
import requests
type_ = "Сериал"
genre = "Вампиры"
country = "Япония"
year = "2005"

params = {
    '?type=': type_,
    '&genre=': genre,
    '&country': country,
    '=&year=': year
}


headers = {
    'User-Agend': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 OPR/83.0.4254.70 (Edition 
Yx GX 03)'
}
resp = requests.get(f'https://anime777.ru/api/rand', params, headers = 
headers).json()
print(resp['title'])
print(resp['other_title'])
```